# required field validator in published mod

Tags: asp.net

while working in debug mode on my development computer my required field validator and
RegularExpressionValidator

work correctly.

but when I publish the site. it dosent works when the user click the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

To validate a Model in ASP.NET, when you specify the `required` attribute, it runs on the **server-side**. In order for the Model validation to take place in the method you use, when the submit `<button>` is clicked, the `ModelState.IsValid` check must be performed by going to the `HttpPost` method of the `View`.

If you want the model to be evaluated on the **client-side** first, you can use a plugin like the [JQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). When you use this plugin, the information whether the Model is correct or not is directly reflected on the page after filling an `<input>` element. Otherwise, the user has to click submit `<button>` to see if the validation is valid.

---

###### References

- [jQuery Validation With ASP.NET Web Form](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ee01e6/jquery-validation-with-Asp-Net-web-form/)
- [Client-Side Model Validation](https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/models/client-side-model-validation/)